# sk_buff memory management confusion

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm new to the kernel (well used to know some things quite well 20 years ago) and trying to understand the memory management of a network packet. Current drivers call one of the following functions when polled:

1. `netif_receive_skb`
2. `napi_gro_receive`

There are a few thing that confuse me. As the kernel tries to be zero copy, I see that if the packet is small, then the drivers allocate a buffer and copy the packet into it and attach the buffer to the `sk_buff`. The way I've understood the code is that if a packet is larger, then the buffer into which the device did DMA is removed from the ring buffer and given to the `sk_buff` and a new buffer is given to the ring buffer instead.

Now what confuses me:

1. As a userspace programmer I'm used to seeing pointers to buffers, i.e. char* or whatever. The `sk_buff` structure talks about pages, so is the packet payload not wired into the page table? Why do we use a page abstraction?
2. `__netif_receive_skb()` talks about this PFMEMALLOC skbs. What are they, when are they created and why and by whom?

Are there any sources that cover a somewhat up-to-date version of the `sk_buff`. A lot of good Linux books were written before 2010, but they are completely obsolete in this area as the current `sk_buff` struct doesn't resemble much the old one.

Also would there be a particular simple NIC driver where the code that creates the skb out of the network packet would be easy to follow? The more high-performance devices are quite a bit more complex.

*Offtopic*: A related problem is that I couldn't find a way to list all (and only those) git commits in the kernel source that modified the `sk_buff` struct. Maybe reading those commits over the past decade would help piece together how it has evolved from those obsolete sources. Anyone know how to do this?